# Check whether value is key of another pair pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I guess the answer to this question might be too obvious.

Yet I would like to know how to get a list of values that are not present as key for any pair in my RDD e.g.

```
pairs = [(3,2),(1,3),(1,4)] to [2,4]
```

```py
keys = pairs.keys().distinct()
```

Now i want to filter the values of pairs and give back only those
that are not in keys, something like:

```py
filteredValues = pairs.values().filter(lambda x: x not in keys)
```

Error I get:

```
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

So I see obviously that the problem is that I use keys (RDD2) inside of pairs' (RDD1) filtering function. 
The question is, how can I overcome that in still get my filtering right?

Constructive help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading this question I thought of a self-join. Not sure if it's the simplest way to do it though:

```
  val myRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1,1),(2,2),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(1,6)))

  val myRdd2 = myRdd.map(x => (x._2, x._1))     // swap values and keys
    .leftOuterJoin(myRdd)                       // and left-join with the original rdd
    .filter(x => x._2._2 == None)
    .map(x => x._1)
    .distinct()
```

LeftJoin returns these tuples (see below), so last three steps (filter, map, distinct) are needed to filter out the result to get just "6"

```
...
(1,(1,Some(6)))
(6,(5,None))
(6,(1,None))
(5,(4,Some(6)))
...
```

Comment: thanks Mate! One minor question for general understanding. An obvious way to get there would be to just call collect for the keys. This however, would kill the efficiency of pyspark since all data is collected to the driver note, right? 

filteredValues = pairs.values().filter(lambda x: x not in keys).collect()

Comment: That's right. collect will convert a spark distributed collection (rdd) to a python list on a driver node. If your dataset is not too big (fits into the memory of the driver process), you can do that and then process it in a pure pythonic way. But then you'd be using Spark to just "download", not "process" you data